# method DESCRIBE failed: 453 Not Enough Bandwidth - OpenCv python

Tags: python, opencv, rtsp

I' m trying to open two rtsp streams using opencv python, when I open only one stream I don't get this error, but when I try to open two or more streams the error occurs. My server is a NVR.

```
import os
from imutils.video import VideoStream, FileVideoStream, FPS
import cv2
import numpy as np

data1= "20201229T171900z"
data2= "20201229T172200z"
rtsp1 = "rtsp://user:pass@192.168.0.4:554/streaming/tracks/101?"
rtsp1 = rtsp1 + "starttime="+data1+"&endtime="+data2

rtsp2 = "rtsp://user:pass@192.168.0.4:554/streaming/tracks/201?"
rtsp2 = rtsp2 + "starttime="+data1+"&endtime="+data2
    

vs1 = VideoStream(rtsp1).start()
vs2 = VideoStream(rtsp2).start()


while(True):
  frame1 = vs1.read()   
  frame2 = vs2.read()   


  frame1 = cv2.resize(frame1, (400,400))
  frame2 = cv2.resize(frame2, (400,400))   
  esquerda = np.concatenate((frame1, frame2), axis=0)
    
  cv2.imshow('img', esquerda)
  key = cv2.waitKey(1)

  if key == ord("q"):
    break

vs1.stop()
vs2.stop()
```

Comment: Depends on the server. Error is sort of self explanatory, server returns you an error message that indicates that it cannot send you two streams at the same time. This fix is up to the server side, it could be max clients, max connections per client, or max bandwidth ..

Comment: Thanks rasjani, I tried to change a lot of configs in my NVR, which is the server, but nothing worked. When I open the web interface of the NVR I can see more than one camera, so I don't think that its a problem on the server side. I think the problem is some configuration in the connection, maybe a parameter on the RTSP URL.